# catkin and dynamic_reconfigure: Could not run dynamic reconfigure file

Tags: catkin, cmake, bloom-release, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I'm currently migrating package per package all the nodes and stacks we've created and I'm having some trouble with catkin and dynamic reconfigure in package [camera1394stereo](https://github.com/srv/camera1394stereo/).
I've re-followed the dynamic_reconfigure tutorials in catkin mode in ros.org, but they did not help.

I have a node and a nodelet inside a package, with its corresponding "cfg" folder in it. In the CMakeLists I have

```
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(cfg/Camera1394Stereo.cfg)
```

before the 'catkin_package()' line, as well as the dynamic_reconfigure dependencies in both CMakeLists and package.xml.

In my machine and in the other machines we have here at work, this package compiles and works. However, when I send my package to the build farm using bloom, this is the error I get:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/dynamic_reconfigure/cmake/extras.cmake:47 (message):
  Could not run dynamic reconfigure file 'cfg/Camera1394Stereo.cfg': the
  rosdep view is empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and 'rosdep update'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:31 (generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options)
```

The output of the buildfarm is here

http://jenkins.willowgarage.com:8080/job/ros-groovy-camera1394stereo_sourcedeb/

I have already made some changes in the cfg file, such as removing the roslib dependecies, and I have re-checked the CMakeLists.txt, but I could not solve this. Has anyone faced this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69583/catkin-and-dynamic_reconfigure:-could-not-run-dynamic-reconfigure-file/) by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1471 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-07-29**:
@Dirk Thomas is this a missing dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The file in the repo (https://github.com/srv/camera1394stereo/blob/groovy/cfg/Camera1394Stereo.cfg#L36) indicates that it imports the old version of dynamic reconfigure intended to be used only with rosbuild:

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator import *
```

Please take a look at the tutorial http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure/Tutorials/HowToWriteYourFirstCfgFile describing how to write the cfg file (watch out to select catkin at the top, not rosbuild). For catkin based packages the import line is subtly different:

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *
```

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Miquel Massot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2515/miquel-massot/) on 2013-07-29**:
Thank you! I did not notice the '_catkin' end. I've now sent a pull request with this change. It was finally built!